# how to make a maze array in C?

Tags: c, maze

I'm trying to write a C program to generate a 2d array for a maze with 1 as the wall and 0 as a path with the recursive backtracking algorithm. I want all four boundaries to be the wall with only the starting point. However, when I print the array, there are always two boundaries used as a path. How can I solve this problem?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdbool.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>

#define MAX_SIZE 20

void generateMaze(int maze[MAX_SIZE][MAX_SIZE], int row, int col, int width, int height);
void printMaze(int maze[MAX_SIZE][MAX_SIZE], int width, int height);

int main() {
    int width = 20;  // Width of the maze
    int height = 20; // Height of the maze

    int maze[MAX_SIZE][MAX_SIZE];

    // Initialize maze with walls
    for (int i = 0; i < height; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < width; j++) {
            maze[i][j] = 1;
        }
    }

    srand(time(NULL));  // Seed the random number generator

    generateMaze(maze, 1, 0, width, height);  // Generate the maze starting from position (0, 0)
    // start position must avoid the four corner
    
    printMaze(maze, width, height);           // Print the generated maze

    return 0;
}

void generateMaze(int maze[MAX_SIZE][MAX_SIZE], int row, int col, int width, int height) {
    int directions[4][2] = {{0, 2}, {2, 0}, {0, -2}, {-2, 0}};  // Right, Down, Left, Up
    int shuffle[4] = {0, 1, 2, 3};

    // Shuffle the directions randomly
    for (int i = 3; i > 0; i--) {
        int j = rand() % (i + 1);
        int temp = shuffle[i];
        shuffle[i] = shuffle[j];
        shuffle[j] = temp;
    }

    // Mark the current cell as empty space
    maze[row][col] = 0;

    for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
        int dx = directions[shuffle[i]][0];
        int dy = directions[shuffle[i]][1];
        int newRow = row + dy;  // Neighbor row
        int newCol = col + dx;  // Neighbor column
        int midRow = row + dy / 2;  // Midpoint row
        int midCol = col + dx / 2;  // Midpoint column

        // Check if the neighbour coordinates are within the maze boundaries
        if (newRow >= 0 && newRow < height && newCol >= 0 && newCol < width && maze[newRow][newCol] == 1) {
            // Carve a path between the current cell and the neighbour
            maze[midRow][midCol] = 0;
            generateMaze(maze, newRow, newCol, width, height);  // Recursively generate the maze from the neighbor cell
        }
    }
}

void printMaze(int maze[MAX_SIZE][MAX_SIZE], int width, int height) {
    for (int i = 0; i < height; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < width; j++) {
            if (maze[i][j] == 1) {
                printf("# ");  // Print wall
            } else {
                printf("  ");  // Print empty space
            }
        }
        printf("\n");
    }
}
```

```
the output is as follows

# # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # 
  #           #                       # 
  #   # # #   #   # # # # # # #   # # # 
  #   #       #   #           #       # 
  # # #   # # #   #   # # #   # # #   # 
      #   #       #   #           #   # 
# #   #   #   # # # # #   # # #   #   # 
  #   #       #           #       #   # 
  #   # # #   # # #   # # #   # # #   # 
  #       #           #       #       # 
  # # #   # # # # # # #   # # #   #   # 
      #           #       #   #   #   # 
  #   # # # # #   # # #   #   #   # # # 
  #           #       #       #       # 
  # # # # # # # # #   # # # # # # #   # 
                  #   #       #       # 
  # # # # #   # # #   #   #   #   #   # 
      #       #       #   #   #   #   # 
# #   #   # # #   # # #   #   #   #   # 
      #                   #       #   #
```

Comment: Start with a much smaller maze, the smallest that exhibits the problem. Then use a [debugger](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25385173/what-is-a-debugger-and-how-can-it-help-me-diagnose-problems) to step through the code line by line, while monitoring variables and their values, to see what happens. Use pencil and paper to draw and redraw the maze as your code works on it. Hopefully this should help you find out when and where things go wrong, or make you see it in a different light to help you solve the problem in another way.

Comment: You initiate the recursion with `generateMaze(maze, 1, 0, width, height);` with an **odd** row but **even** column starting point. But you move in steps of `2` units. Apart from that your boundary test `newRow >= 0 && newRow < height && newCol >= 0 && newCol < width` does allow you to carve out cells along the edges.

Comment: I would think your maze needs an **odd** number of rows and columns, if you want walls around the edges.

Comment: OT: Instead of initializing both `width` and `height` in the `main` function to the magic number `20`, why not use the macro `MAX_SIZE`? Why use variables in the first place? You can use the macro in the loops and when calling your functions. In fact, you don't need `width` and `height` variables or arguments anywhere, just use the macro. That will make it very easy to change the size of the maze with only a small single edit.